# Pop OS Kernel Update Failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, kernel, pop-os

I'm using Pop! OS Version 20.10. When i'm running any apt command always show error kernel not fully installed. This is the log :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Sedang menata linux-image-5.8.0-7625-generic (5.8.0-7625.26~1604441477~20.10~d41e407) ... 
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.8.0-7625-generic (5.8.0-7625.26~1604441477~20.10~d41e407) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.8.0-7625-generic
Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200908/5.8.0-7625-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module wireguard includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE di
rective which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-7625-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub.Drive     : ERROR    Could not find a block device for the a partition. This is a critical error and we cannot continue.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.esp_fs = self.get_part_dev(self.esp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 94, in get_part_dev
    raise NoBlockDevError('Couldn\'t find the block device for %s' % path)
kernelstub.drive.NoBlockDevError: Couldn't find the block device for /boot/efi
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub exited with return code 174
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-7625-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-7625-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Ada kesalahan saat memproses: 
 linux-image-5.8.0-7625-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
I've solved this error by mounting efi system partition to /mnt/efi

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/efi
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with the following configuration :

**Host**: Alienware m15 R6
**OS**: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
**Kernel**: 5.13.0-39-generic
**CPU**: 11th Gen Intel i7-11800H

NOTE : I have other distros on my laptop and after installing PopOs I needed to boot in live-CD to run Boot-repair and reinstall grub.

First i had the following problem at startup :

```
job is running for /dev/disk/by-partuiid/d06ca1c2-6183-46cd-af2a-eb2070aba2a1
```

My Linux distribution could not mount the partition with EFI and apparently after inspection the UID was not good at all

```
PARTUUID=d06ca1c2-6183-46cd-af2a-eb2070aba2a1  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=fb8c454b-6994-4968-bd74-cdc46823527a  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
```

But I had no disk with UID d06ca1c2-6183-46cd-af2a-eb2070aba2a1

So I used gnome-disks to identify the UUID of my EFI partition, and change the file like that

```
UUID=8DC8-AACD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=fb8c454b-6994-4968-bd74-cdc46823527a  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
```

And after reboot I could upgrade "linux-image".

---

**NOTE**

This error can also be due to insufficient space in the partition with the EFI